# Flatten array of object of array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of categories, and inside that I have items. I rather want an array of items, but I also want some of the properties of the category inside the item objets

Basically I would like to flatten this:

```
[
 {catname: "caregory1", items: [{ name: "item1" }, {name: "item2"}] }
 {catname: "caregory2", items: [{ name: "item3" }, {name: "item4"}, {name: "item5"}] }
]
```

into this?

```
[
 {catname: "caregory1", name: "item1" }
 {catname: "caregory1", name: "item2" }
 {catname: "caregory2", name: "item3" },
 {catname: "caregory2", name: "item4" },
 {catname: "caregory2", name: "item5" }
]
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMap()` and `map()` for this.

- Use `flatMap()` on the main array and isolate the `items` property and rest of the properties using object destructuring and spread stynax
- Then use `map()` on the `items` properties of array and return the properties of nested object with properties other than `items` of parent item.

```js
const arr = [
 {catname: "caregory1", items: [{ name: "item1" }, {name: "item2"}] },
 {catname: "caregory2", items: [{ name: "item3" }, {name: "item4"}, {name: "item5"}] }
]

const res = arr.flatMap(({items,...rest}) => items.map(a => ({...a,...rest})))

console.log(res)
```

If `flatMap()` is not supported by browser you are using then use `concat()`

```js
const arr = [
 {catname: "caregory1", items: [{ name: "item1" }, {name: "item2"}] },
 {catname: "caregory2", items: [{ name: "item3" }, {name: "item4"}, {name: "item5"}] }
]

const res = [].concat(...arr.map(({items,...rest}) => items.map(a => ({...a,...rest}))))

console.log(res)
```